# Управление камерой с телефона Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как реализовать вращение камеры вокруг обьекта по оси Y вращением двух пальцев на экране телефона?

С помощью тачей реализовал перемещение и зум. А вот с поворотом проблемы.

Использую Cinemachine Virtual Camera, потому что в ней уже встроен функционал следования за обьектом и напрваление на него. Мне как-то нужно реализовать, что при вращении двумя пальцами будет поворачиваться пустой обьект за которым следует камера.